# Novice to C#: How to use methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a novice programmer and I am working in visual studio using C#.  In a Windows Form Application, Create a form that gets the input from a user from 0-100. You will need to make 3 methods for this application. Your first method must get the users input and validates that the entry is valid. Use logic to ensure the input is accurate, if the user enters an invalid entry throw a message box to the user with the error. The user must have a successful entry to proceed. We will expand on validation and exceptions in Lab 5. Once the score is validated send the score to a second method which assigns a letter grade. Use the following grading schema and use integer values for your scoring. < 60 is a F, >= 60 and < 70
is a D, >= 70 and < 80 is a C, >= 80 and < 90 is a B, >= 90 is an A. Once a grade is assigned pass the score and the letter grade to a Third Method. The third method will handle display and concatenate the results into a single string as displayed in the image below.

This is what I currently have...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab4_Part_1_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set user input to integer.
            int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
            Form1 moto = new Form1();
            lblGrade.Text = moto.NumEnter(score);



        }

        private string NumEnter(int score)
        {
            string result;
            //Set parameters for user input and prompt with textbox if outside parameters.

            if (score < 0 | score > 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a score 0-100.");
                this.txtScore.Text = "";

            }

            //Set parameters for each letter grade
            else if (score >= 0 && score <= 100)
            {
                if (score >= 90)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "A";
                }


                else if (score >= 80)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "B";
                }


               else if (score >= 70)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "C";
                }

               else if (score >= 60)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "D";
                }

               else
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "F";
                }
                return result;

            }

            //Concatenate the input user score and output a message with the letter grade.
            lblGrade.Text = "You entered an " + txtScore.Text + " which is a " +
                lblGrade.Text + " letter grade.";

        }





    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What does it currently do?

Comment: `result = lblGrade.Text = "A";` doesnt do what you think it does...does that compile?

Comment: I did have it working, but without using methods. I have an error for NumEnter... }

        private string NumEnter(int score)
        {

Comment: `I have an error` Generally the more detail you give us the better. 'I have an error' is too vague for us to act on. What is the error? When does it occur? Did you try my suggestion below?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. The error states "Form1.EnterNum(Int)': not all code paths return a value. Yes i tried the code below and it was very helpful in cleaning up and simplifying the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Use at least X methods" = "Don't do everything in one big method." That is all.

For example, instead of this huge method:

```
        private string NumEnter(int score)
        {
            string result;
            //Set parameters for user input and prompt with textbox if outside parameters.

            if (score < 0 | score > 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a score 0-100.");
                this.txtScore.Text = "";

            }

            //Set parameters for each letter grade
            else if (score >= 0 && score <= 100)
            {
                if (score >= 90)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "A";
                }


                else if (score >= 80)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "B";
                }


               else if (score >= 70)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "C";
                }

               else if (score >= 60)
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "D";
                }

               else
                {
                    result = lblGrade.Text = "F";
                }
                return result;

            }

            //Concatenate the input user score and output a message with the letter grade.
            lblGrade.Text = "You entered an " + txtScore.Text + " which is a " +
                lblGrade.Text + " letter grade.";

        }
```

You could instead break it down into four short methods:

```
        private string GetLetterGrade(int score)
        {
            if (score < 0 | score > 100)
            {
                return null; //not valid score
            }

            if (score >= 90) return "A";
            if (score >= 80) return "B";
            if (score >= 70) return "C";
            if (score >= 60) return "D";
            return "F";
        }

        private string NumEnter(int score)
        {
            var grade = GetLetterGrade(score);
            if (grade == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a score 0-100.");
                ClearUserInput();
                return;
            }

            DisplayScore(score, grade);
        }

        public void ClearUserInput()
        {
            this.txtScore.Text = "";
        }

        public void DisplayScore(int score, string grade)
        {
            this.lblGrade.Text = String.Format("You entered an {0} which is a {1}", score, grade);
        }
```

As a rule, programmers should try to break things down into smaller methods. This practice greatly reduces complexity and makes the code easier to read (Some engineers would actually state a hard rule that no method should ever be bigger than a single screen.)

Also, introducing more methods means introducing more method *names*, which allows a programmer to quickly  understand the purpose of the code without needing to read code comments-- from my code snippet, for example, it is very clear what is intended by calling `ClearUserInput` and `DisplayScore`, without having to dig into the code inside those functions, and without understanding the purpose of the textboxes on the form. Not a big deal in this exercise but extremely helpful in real-world applications, where there may be dozens of controls on the form.

See also

[Functions Should Be Short And Sweet, But Why?](http://sam-koblenski.blogspot.com/2014/01/functions-should-be-short-and-sweet-but.html)

[The art of writing small and plain functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/the-art-of-writing-small-and-plain-functions/)

[Can a function be too short?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/can-a-function-be-too-short)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Form1 moto = new Form1();
lblGrade.Text = moto.NumEnter(score);
```

to:

```
lblGrade.Text = NumEnter(score);
```

*There is no need to `new` up a new `Form1` since your code is already running in a `Form1`.*

You should also change your lines like:

```
result = lblGrade.Text = "A";
```

to just return the result:

```
return "A";
```

And let `btnValidate_Click` take care of setting `lblGrade.Text`.